# Problem with Solve Function: It gives wrong solution!

Tags: equation-solving

I tried to run the codes

```
$Assumptions = {a, b, c, d, q} \[Element] Reals
a = Sqrt[1 - c^2 Sin[q]^2];
d = -Sqrt[1 - b^2 Csc[q]^2];
Solve[-a b - c d Sin[q]^2 == 0, b]
```

and the output is

```
{{b -> -c Sin[q]^2}, {b -> c Sin[q]^2}}
```

Only one of the "solutions" is the right answer, the second one. Why did it include the first one, the wrong solution? How do I make it only give the correct one?

Comment: It seems to me you are making assumptions about your variables that you know, *but have not given to Mathematica* (everything is assumed to be complex-valued unless indicated otherwise). *Mathematica* is not a mind reader.

Comment: @J.M. I just added the assumption for all variables to be real, {a,b,c,d,q} and it still give the same output. Am I missing something?

Comment: What does `Solve[b Sqrt[1 - c^2 Sin[q]^2] - Sqrt[1 - b^2 Csc[q]^2] c Sin[q]^2 == 0, b, Reals]` give for you?

Comment: @J.M. It gives two solutions with ConditionalExpression. It's a bit messy.

Comment: That's *Mathematica* being careful, since the assumption of real variables was imposed. Have a look at the conditions perhaps and verify that they're what you want? You can then extract the solution afterwards from it.

Comment: I tried to plot taking b as x and q as y and using different values of c, and this gives idea of how many values have  that make the whole to cross z==0 ...

Comment: `Solve` doesn't take the option `Assumptions` so it does not make use of `$Assumptions`. Use `Simplify` to simplify the results: `Solve[- a b - c d Sin[q]^2 == 0, b, Reals] // Simplify`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, that works. It's odd that it simplified the wrong solution to be undefined.

Comment: @Bao - I get `{{b -> ConditionalExpression[c Sin[q]^2, 
    c < 0 && -1 < c Sin[q] < 1]}, {b -> 
   ConditionalExpression[c Sin[q]^2, c > 0 && -1 < c Sin[q] < 1]}}`. You probably need to `Clear` your variables or start with a fresh kernel.